# Dual space of quotient of C$^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

I'm interested in understanding what the dual space of a quotient of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ looks like.

Let $A$ denote a $C^*$-algebra and $I$ a closed ideal therein. Denote the dual space of $A$ by $B$. I think one can say something like:

*The dual space $B_I$ of the quotient $A/I$ is canonically isometrically isomorphic to a weak$^*$ closed subset of B.*

Is this true?

Thank you very much!

Comment: By dual space, you mean the space of continuous linear functionals?

Comment: Additionally, What is weak containment in the context of $C^*$-algebra representations?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Well, I think it's analogous to the notion you might know for groups. $\pi\prec R$ means that the kernel of $\pi$ contains the intersection of kernels of representations in $R$. Or equiv.: One can approximate matrix coefficients of $\pi$ by (sums of) those of $R$. ...roughly. See for example Fell's works on dual spaces of $C^*$-algebras

Comment: And to whoever voted close on my question: Might you suggest why and/or edit the question accordingly if you think it's malposed?

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with algebras. Whnever you have a closed subspace $L$ of a normed (or, more generally, locally convex) vector space $X$, then the dual of the quotient $X/L$ (with the quotient locally convex topology) is (canonically isomorphic to) $L^\perp=\lbrace f\in X^\ast: f|_L=0\rbrace$ which is weak$^\ast$-closed in $X^*$.